# How to make divs have table-like borders?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using bootstrap grid I managed to have div blocks inside row which should appear with border. Each div in the row must appear same size. So far I have:
**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 feed-entry  ng-repeat="feed in feeds" ng-scope"></div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.row {
    display: table;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #333333;
}

[class*="col-"] {
    float: none;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.feed-entry{
    border-right-color: #737373;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-right-style: solid;
    float: left !important;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

The problem that right border of `.feed-entry` is limited to content (div) height. How to fix it?

[image]

Comment: If you want it to look like a table, why not just use a table? Or at least use `display: table`?

Comment: 1. I need responsive design - grid system 2. I use `ng-repeat` to put divs inside a row

Comment: Then use display: table only at the breakpoints where it is appropriate.

Comment: How can I do that in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have works as is *except* you have to remove the `float:left` from `feed-entry`. The fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/zLzjnuuz/